# Para que serve a função addListener?

Tags: javascript

Eu sei usar o `addEventListener`, mas não sei para que serve o `addListener`, pesquisei e não achei nenhuma especificação sobre essa função.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<script>
function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.matches) {
    window.alert("f");
  } else {
   window.alert("a");
  }
}
var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")
myFunction(x)
x.addListener(myFunction)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

O que `addListener` está fazendo nesse trecho de código? e para que ele serve?

Comment: Isso: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener

Comment: O método addListener () da interface MediaQueryList adiciona um ouvinte ao MediaQueryListener que executará uma função de retorno de chamada personalizada em resposta à alteração do status da consulta de mídia.

Comment: Muito obrigado ajudou bastante

Comment: @MauryDeveloper Pq vc não posta uma resposta em vez de comentar?

Comment: @Sam queria ver se minha resposta tava certo. Eu odeio respostas ruins.

Comment: @MauryDeveloper vc simplesmente copiou o texto traduzido de https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener

Comment: Coloquei a fonte. Não se preocupe,tava inglês.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá.

## MediaQueryList.addListener()

O método `addListener()` da interface MediaQueryList adiciona um ouvinte ao MediaQueryListener que executará uma função de retorno de chamada personalizada em resposta à alteração do status da consulta de mídia.

Isso é basicamente um alias para `EventTarget.addEventListener()`, para fins de compatibilidade com versões anteriores. Os navegadores mais antigos devem usar `addListener` em vez de `addEventListener`, pois o MediaQueryList só herda do EventTarget em navegadores mais recentes.

## Sintaxe

`MediaQueryList.addListener(func)`

## Parâmetro

`func`: Uma função ou referência de função representando a função de retorno de chamada que você deseja executar quando o status da consulta de mídia é alterado.

Esse método não retorna nenhum valor.

## Exemplo

```js
var mql = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)');

function screenTest(e) {
  if (e.matches) {
    /* the viewport is 600 pixels wide or less */
    para.textContent = 'This is a narrow screen — less than 600px wide.';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  } else {
    /* the viewport is more than than 600 pixels wide */
    para.textContent = 'This is a wide screen — more than 600px wide.';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }
}

mql.addListener(screenTest);
```

## Navegadores compatíveis

- Chrome +9
- Microsoft Edge
- Firefox +6
- Opera +12.1
- Safari +5

## Fonte

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086372/how-does-addlistener-work-with-matchmedia-api

Comment: Vou dar um -1 por simplesmente copiar um texto em vez de escrever com as suas próprias palavras explicando o funcionamento da função. Citar a fonte é sempre bom, mas explicar com as próprias palavras, se domina o assunto, é o ideal.

Comment: @Sam Desculpe,vou adiciona minha palavra e tu editar? Eu sou ruim em português.